# Running a command at start up on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, startup

I would like to automatically run "xclock" after the system boots up and display the clock,

so I created myclock.sh file, with command xclock inside. I then moved the file to /etc/init.d/ made it executable:

sudo chmod +x myclock.sh

and included it on the run levels:

sudo update-rc.d myclock.sh defaults

However I still do not get the clock at boot up,is there anything Im doing wrong. The ultimate goal is to automatically start up a certain application in a remote machine ( that I can only connect to using ssh), I need the application running all the time when the machine is on.

Comment: Have you tried putting the full path to xclock in your shell script? Does it show anything in the logs (error/warning at boot up)?

Answer (score 2):

X applications can't be in a startup-scripts, as the X environment isn't started yet. Instead try to create a file `.xsessionrc` in your home directory, containing:

```
exec xclock
```

The file doesn't have to be executable.

This file is executed when the you log into an X session.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, however as I mentioned there is a console app I need running as soon the remote machine boots up even if no user has logged in

Comment: @Obakeng From the [`xclock` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclock): "xclock - analog / digital clock for X". It's an application that needs the X environment, i.e. the graphical environment in Unix-like systems. It can not run in a console, only as a window in X.

Comment: @Obakeng For how a startup-script should look like, look at `/etc/init.d/skeleton`, which you can copy and modify as needed.